# Sass / Compass Font Awesome issues (displaying odd glyphs instead of icons?)

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, font-awesome, compass

Sass 3.4.9
Compass 1.0.1
Font Awesome 4.2

I'm compiling Font Awesome 4.2 (as Sass) with Compass. Instead of intended icons, I get random glpyhs. I'm new to Sass/Compass. This is also my first post ever on StackOverflow (so cool, but I hope I'm asking my question right and what not!). I've googled and searched here until my stack overflowed to no avail. Cannot seem to find anyone else with this same problem.

Directory structure:

```
[public_html]
../config.rb
..[assets]
....[fonts]
....../FontAwesome.otf
....../fontawesome-webfont.eot
....../fontawesome-webfont.svg
....../fontawesome-webfont.ttf
....../fontawesome-webfont.wo
....[stylesheets]
......[css]
........screen.css
......[sass]
......../screen.scss
........[font-awesome]
........../_bordered-pulled.scss
........../_core.scss
........../_fixed-width.scss
........../_icons.scss
........../_larger.scss
........../_list.scss
........../_mixins.scss
........../_path.scss
........../_rotated-flipped.scss
........../_spinning.scss
........../_stacked.scss
........../_variables.scss
........../font-awesome.scss
```

File "config.rb":

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "/assets/stylesheets/css"
sass_dir = "/assets/stylesheets/sass"
images_dir = "/assets/images"
javascripts_dir = "/assets/scripts/js"
output_style = :compact
relative_assets = true
line_comments = false
```

File "public_html/assets/stylesheets/sass/screen.scss":

```
@import "font-awesome/font-awesome";
```

File "public_html/assets/stylesheets/sass/font-awesome/font-awesome.scss":

```
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "path";
@import "core";
@import "larger";
@import "fixed-width";
@import "list";
@import "bordered-pulled";
@import "spinning";
@import "rotated-flipped";
@import "stacked";
@import "icons";
```

File "public_html/assets/stylesheets/sass/font-awesome/_variables.scss":

```
$fa-var-building: "\f1ad";
$fa-var-car: "\f1b9";
$fa-var-envelope-o: "\f003";
```

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/css/screen.css">
...
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-building"></i> Company</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-car"></i> Services</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact</a></li>
```

Output:

```
ï† Company ï†¹ Services ï€ƒ Contact
```

Chrome Dev tools Network tab data:

```
Request URL: /assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 Not Modified
Connection:Keep-Alive
Date:Mon, 12 Jan 2015 10:49:56 GMT
ETag:"246ded-ffac-5018b0cc6f280"
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=98
Server:Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
```

*** EDIT ***

Playing with Chrom Dev tools, if I inspect icon element, it shows:

```
.fa-building:before { content: "ï†­"; } // resulting data in compass compiled screen.css
```

if I change that to:

```
.fa-building:before { content: "\f1ad"; } // source data in original FA _variables.scss
```

it works correctly. How do I prevent Compass/Sass from converting my escape strings to unicode characters?

Answer (score 6):

Solution:

Add to top of font-awesome.scss:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

Compass now compiles with escape codes intact versus BOM. Icons now display correctly.

Comment: You should accept your answer as it happened a solution for you

Answer (score 4):

A combination of the above answers did the trick for me:

Correct meta tag in `<head>`:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

UTF-8 encoded CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

And additionally, *ensure the `@charset` declaration is the very first line in your CSS file*. This tripped me up as I was performing Gulp processing, including copyright stamping processed source and did so at such a point that the `@charset` rule was not the first line - replicable bug.

Also, for people who have this issue but cannot replicate it reliably (as I couldn't) - use the Audit feature in Chrome devtools. For me, an Audit was performed (did not display the bug) and finished it's job, the resulting page that displayed always showed this encoding bug.

Comment: Great tip on how to predictably reproduce the issue. Thanks, mate!

Answer (score 0):

I solved a very similar issue by removing `charset` from my scss and removing **quote characters** from the utf codes

```
.fa-building:before { content: \f1ad; }
```

Comment: For me, removing the quotes didn't work. The compiled css has the rule: "content: \f1ad", which Chrome ignores as invalid.

Comment: Yah, it's missing single/double quote.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem as this recently.

It turns out it was because I had omitted the following tag in my HTML head:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

(face palm)

Once I had added that in, my compiled CSS displayed the correct icons.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution here: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/659#issuecomment-71759457

Remove first slash in your variable, eg:

```
$fa-var-building: "\f1ad";
// Should be:
$fa-var-building: "f1ad";
```

Then use this syntax in content code:

```
.icon:before {
  { content: #{"\"\\"}#{$icon-code + "\""}; }
}
```

Example: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/d484e00fe9243d4ba0c8

Answer (score -2):

It is clear that you are using wrong path, so font file is not found.
You are using relative path in File "public_html/assets/stylesheets/sass/screen.scss":

```
@import "font-awesome/font-awesome";
```

May be this is a reason

Comment: Correct font path "../../fonts" is defined in file "public_html/assets/stylesheets/sass/font-awesome/_variables.scss" -- Also, the compiled "public_html/assets/stylesheets/css/screen.css" reflects contents of all imported files as it should