# FontAwesome is broken

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-5

i have a website and use 'FontAwesome' for displayed , but sometimes a broken font and content in css change runtime to an.
for example :
'fa fa-bars' taht in css content is "/f0c9"

but sometimes  by refresh form content change to "ïƒ‰"

how to resolve this problem.

Comment: you might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901023/sass-compass-font-awesome-issues-displaying-odd-glyphs-instead-of-icons) out